# Константа в классе

Tags: c++

Нужно, чтобы при создании объекта класса выполнялась функция высчитывающая константу, которую потом можно использовать не вызывая заново эту функцию. Т.е. функция должна выполняться один раз, а доступ к константе получить потом можно всегда.

Как это сделать?

Comment: [Постоянные выражения C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3ffb821x.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте переменную статической, и высчитываете ее перед созданием экземпляров класса.

Comment: что значит отлично от начального?

Comment: эээээээээээ''''''''''''''

Comment: Этот вариант подходит, если вы знаете, что значение переменной никогда не будет меньше нуля. Значит перед созданием первого объекта устанавливаем значения статической переменной в -1.

Comment: ок так бы сразу и сказал. а если у меня 5 конструкторов че в каждом писать одно и то же?(

Comment: При таком подходе - да

Comment: лан спасибо)))))

Comment: @SanekZhitnik, что Вы пишете? Какое высчитывание статической переменной в конструкторе?! Статическая переменная (константа она или нет) должна определяться вне всякого конструктора, и вообще вне любого нестатического метода.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Константа не зависит от экземпляра класса.**

Высчитывать константу при создании экземпляра класса избыточно. Гораздо эффективнее её вычислять при первом обращении. В этом случае мы избегаем ненужных вычислений, если константа нам не понадобится.

```
class Test 
{
    private :
        static int calcConst()
        {
            // Вычисляем константу.
            return вычисленное_значение;
        }
    public :
        static int getConst()
        {
            static int c = calcConst();
            return c;
        }  
};
```

2. **Константа зависит от экземпляра класса.**

Чтобы избежать необходимости вставки вызова функции-вычислителя в каждый конструктор, можно воспользоваться возможностью, предоставляемой стандартом `c++11`:

```
class Test 
{
    private :
        int calcConst()
        {
            // Вычисляем константу.
            return вычисленное_значение;
        }
        const int c = calcConst();
    public :
        int getConst() const
        {
            return c;
        }  
};
```

Если константа зависит от каких-либо параметров, передаваемых в конструктор, то необходимо учитывать порядок инициализации членов.

1) Члены класса инициализируются в порядке их объявления. Т.е. все члены, от которых зависит наша константа, должны быть объявлены выше неё.

2) Вначале выполняется инициализация членов в списке инициализации конструктора (то, что идёт после двоеточия), причём порядок членов в этом списке не имеет значения, инициализация идёт в порядке объявления и только затем выполняется тело конструктора. Иными словами, если конструктор должен инициализировать члены, необходимые для вычисления нашей константы, он должен это сделать в списке инициализации.

Answer (score 2):

A.h:

```
Class A
{
public:
   static const int MYCONST = 1;
   static const std::string OTHER;
   A();
....
}
```

A.cpp:

```
A::OTHER = "my string";
A::A() {
...
}
```